# Is it possible to ask user for current location without starting corelocation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, core-location

I have and app that use core location for tracking.
But when the app starts I don't start any tracking until the user click on a button "GO".
When user click on go I get message "App want to use your current location...allow/don't allow".
Is it possible to configure app that ask this question on app startup without starting location services?
*(As app can but doesn't have to use gps but I want to mention this to the user on startup)*

Answer (score 2):

No You will have to ask for enabling location services from Users

Comment: Maybe you don't understand. I have to ask for enabling location services on start of the application. But I don't want to start any location start on app start. Basically my question is is it possible to configure app to ask this without starting location services on application startup.

Comment: you can do this by showing a simple alert. save the value enetered by user yes/ no from alert button. But disadvantage is this that when you will on location ios will aks for permissions again.  :(

Comment: Hmm there must be some other option.

Comment: I dont think so.. If you find any . Then plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can find way around this by invoking CL when the app first starts, but don't actually use it until the "Go" button is pressed.

As you currently have it, at least the user is informed that location information is required for that specific task, whereas at app launch, the purpose of location tracking may be unknown and suspicious.